# IIS 7.0 app pool recycling every minute

Tags: iis-7, application-pool

I've got an app pool that is recycling exactly every minute. The Private memory is set to 1433600KB Virtual memory is set to 2457600KB (yes its a lot). The recycling regular time interval is left at its default value of 1740. From what I can see the memory limit is not near being reached when the recycling happens. I can't find anything shceduled on the server that could be causing this either.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had the same issue. Don't know if is solution for you, but we disabled Virtual memory recycling setup (keep Private memory enabled) and app pool stops recycling.

Check this [article about large memory reservations](https://web.archive.org/web/20150516090653/http://www.asprangers.com/post/2012/03/30/Look-who-is-reserving-large-amount-of-virtual-memory-on-64-bit-It-is-Net-GC-heaps.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Ensure recycle logging is turned on for all possible values (right click on the application pool, select "Recycling", then click "next" to see the logging).

Then when it recycles you should receive a "WAS" sourced event in the System Event Viewer that tells you specifically why it recycled.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue. The problem was fixed by changing the Ping Maximum Response Time which was too low.